# Access Struct when struct is in an Slice

Tags: go

I need to generate a Form from the struct below. I need to have access to every field and type on the Doc to generate the Form. My problem is to access the struct fields when they are on an slice.

This is the code

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "time"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "strconv"

)
type TestStruct struct {

    Children22 struct {// I can acess this one ( see code) 
            ID   string
            Name string
        }
    Children23 []struct { // this is not struct it is slice of sruct
            ID1   string    // I would like to access this one
            Name1 string
        }
    Nest struct {
        Children []struct {  // I would like to get to this one too
            ID2   string
            Name2 string
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    var t1 TestStruct
    t1.InterfaceStruct = &InterfaceStruct{}
    main := reflect.ValueOf(&t1)
    err := GetField(main)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error lev 1 = ", err)
            }
    }

func GetField ( f reflect.Value ) error {

    if f.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        fmt.Println("Error not a pointer  ")  
    }
    val := f.Elem()
    lenght := val.NumField()
    for i := 0; i < lenght; i++ {
        typefield := val.Type().Field(i)
        elementType := val.Type().Field(i).Type
        type_filed := val.Type().Field(i).Type.String()
        elemKind    := elementType.Kind()

        fmt.Println("typefield.Name = ", typefield.Name) 
        fmt.Println("elementType    = ", elementType) 
        fmt.Println("what kind =", elemKind )

        if elemKind  ==  reflect.Slice{
            fmt.Println("is a Slice")
            fmt.Println(" Slice type =", val.Field(i).Addr().Elem().Type() )
            // what kind of slice 
            if strings.Contains(type_filed ,"struct") {

                // I do not know how to address the struct inside the slice

            }
        }
        if elemKind  == reflect.Struct {  // check first for time and URL are Struct
            if type_filed != "time.Time" && type_filed != "url.URL" {
            fmt.Println("is a struct ")
             //pass this to function recursive  as   reflect.Value
            newSt := val.Field(i).Addr() // this works fine 
            err := GetField(newSt) // recall the func to get the struct
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error = ", err)
                }
            }
        }
        if elemKind  ==  reflect.Map {
            fmt.Println("is a Map")
        }

    fmt.Println(" ")

    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Please 1st minimize your code, 2nd format it properly (some code is out of syntax highlighting)

Comment: Unless that reflect stuff is absolutely necessary I would get away from it as fast as possible. That being said, if this is supposed to work with arbitrary types, using reflect to find whatever fields are available, you need `GetField` to be recursive. This will never work as you have it because you're not addressing the fact that there could be infinite nesting. When you're working with a struct, and you encounter another struct inside it for example, you should be making a recursive call to `GetField` with the inner struct as it's arg.

Comment: Your code is written in a static manner to deal with one level of nesting. The slice breaks it because it has two levels of nesting; outer->slice->structs but if it were struct->struct->struct you'd be broken just the same. In order to make this really work you'll need to make a recursive call to `GetField` each time you encounter another level of nesting. It's the only way you can traverse some arbitrary struct completely.